# JOIN with '!=' operator

Tags: sql, database, join

The `JOIN` or `INNER JOIN` clauses are usually used with the `=` operator, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
```

I've noticed that it is possible use any operator on `JOIN` clauses. It's possible to use `!=, >=, <=,` etc.

I wonder what utility could has to use another operator in `JOIN` clauses. I think that using i.e `>=, <=, >, <`  maybe doesn't have so much utility, but someone imagine any example where using these could be useful? (I meant with `PRIMARY KEY`)

Further, can anyone tell me if the next query returns *"The rows of both tables that they haven't any relationship with the other"*?

```
SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id != table2.id
```

Comment: Please do some experimenting...  :-)  You'll get some really quick answers that way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical example of a **join by `<`** would be to get all pairs of the values a single column where both items of the pair are distinct from each other.

For an example, see http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ed2a/3

```
create table numbers(val int);

insert into numbers values(1);
insert into numbers values(2);
insert into numbers values(3);
insert into numbers values(4);
```

and the statement:

```
select m.val as first, n.val as second
  from numbers m join numbers n on m.val < n.val
```

delivers the six combinations of the numbers 1 to 4 where both numbers are different:

```
1 2
1 3
1 4
2 3
2 4
3 4
```

An example for **using `<=` in a join** would be a running sum: Based on the same table, if I want to see the actual value of a record, as well as the sum of all records up to the current row, I could use the following statement:

```
select m.val, sum(n.val) as running_sum
 from numbers m join numbers n on n.val <= m.val
group by m.val
order by m.val
```

which returns

```
1  1
2  3
3  6
4 10
```

In real applications, you would normally have at least two columns in the table like an id and a sales value for which you want to show the actual record value and the running total. But for the matter of simplicity, I stayed with the same table model.

Comment: Very nice your last example. I didn't notice that use and it is very useful! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM 
   table1 

   INNER JOIN table2 
   ON Table1.id = Table2.id
   AND Table2.description != 'leave me alone!'
```

---

```
SELECT *
FROM 
   table1 

   INNER JOIN table2 
   ON Table1.id = Table2.id
   AND Table2.due_date <= GETDATE()
```

Answer (score 1):

Joins that use the `=` are called "equijoins"  These joins are the easiest for database engines to optimize.  Other types of joins are called "non-equijoins" (people who name things in databases are not particularly creative ;).

Yes, they are useful.  Say you have a list of values.  One way to count the number of values less than or equal to each number is to use a non-equijoin with aggregation:

```
select t1.number, count(*)
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t2.number <= t1.number
group by t1.number;
```

There are, of course, other ways to do this.  This is to give you an idea of the utility of non-equijoins.

One special type of non-equijoin goes by a special name, `cross join`.  These are useful when you want to get all combinations of rows from two tables -- quite useful in some contexts.

Your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 INNER JOIN
     table2
     ON table1.id != table2.id;
```

Might be better understood as:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 CROSS JOIN
     table2
WHERE table1.id <> table2.id;
```

These return exactly the same thing.  But the second emphasizes that you are getting all combinations of rows from `t1` and `t2`, except for the ones where the two `id`s are the same (in some sense, the "diagonal").